# Split or Copy file skipping byte Count

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, powershell

I am looking for a windows native cmd, or powershell command to emulate the same actions of `'dd'` in linux.

I have 2 merged files, one appended to another, and I know the byte pointer for the beginning and end.

In linux I simply use `dd` and skipping to the appropriate pointer.

I can't for the life of me find a native command in Windows which does something similar.

I had considered inflating the smaller of the two files so they are exactly the same size, then using the `split` command however Windows also doesn't seem to have it.

Any options in Powershell | Cmd ?

**Please not, I am not looking for 3rd party solutions**

Comment: Windows does not traditionally allow raw disk access. I'm sure theres a way, but they went to a lot of trouble to prevent operations like those that `dd` exists for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell! There are a handful of ways you could do this, but perhaps the clearest method is to use [`Get-Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6)/`gc` and [`Set-Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6)/`sc` to move bytes around. Suppose we had a `merged.ext` file where the first hundred bytes are one file and the rest are another:

```
$bytes = gc .\merged.ext -Encoding Byte -Raw
sc .\part1.ext ([byte[]]($bytes | select -First 100)) -Encoding Byte
sc .\part2.ext ([byte[]]($bytes | select -Skip 100)) -Encoding Byte
```

Weirdly, `Set-Content` when working with bytes (`-Encoding Byte`) wants its input to be exactly a byte array, not just a sequence that happens to contain bytes, so we need to cast explicitly to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike EOF, there's no beginning of file indicator available to batch scripts on Win CMD, which doesn't have direct access to MFT or FAT. The first few bytes of file can be accessed by reading the file itself, or truncated to (keep) only the first part of the file with `fsutil`.

```
REM Raw binary split first part of file
FSUTIL file seteof <file> <size>
```

There's no utility or command to keep/extract the latter part of the file in CMD. A workaround would be to hex dump, remove the first bytes, then `certutil` or `forfiles` the remainder back to the required 2nd part of the binary file.